# Instrumentation of the Rite of Spring

Tags: instruments, orchestration

I am studying Stravinsky's Rite of Spring (just for my own pleasure) and I have the Dover Miniature Score.

On the instrumentation page, I see entries such as these:

Piccolo

3 Flutes (Fl. III = Picc. II)

Alto Flute (G)

Is this saying that the third flautist will double with a piccolo?  So, there may be a need for 3 flutes and 1 piccolo or 2 flutes and 2 piccolos but never 3 flutes and 2 piccolos.  On the other hand, there should be a dedicated player for the alto flute.

There are similar entries for oboe and English horn, bassoon and contrabassoon, etc.

P.S. I have only surprisingly recently encountered the term "English horn".  Despite being in England, I am much more used to "cor anglais".

Comment: Re English horn - I remembered this from a course I once took [_**English Horn - History and etymology**_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cor_anglais#History_and_etymology) : _cor anglais is French for English horn, but the instrument is neither from England nor related to the various conical-bore brass instruments called "horns"....  gave rise in German-speaking central Europe to the Middle High German name engellisches Horn, meaning angelic horn..._ More there.

Comment: I immediately recognised what English horn referred to.  Apart from knowing the literal meaning of cor anglais being between the oboes and bassoons was a big clue.  It just sounded odd to me.  Rather like Americans talking of "British units" for pound, foot, etc; we don't say that.

Comment: I understand. I'm just pointing out that the name really doesn't make much sense - indeed, we really shouldn't say that. :)

Comment: Agreed.  A varient of oboe would be more appropriate.  However, I am used to cor anglais so it sounds familiar while English horn still sounds odd.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(Disclaimer: I didn't go through the whole score to verify)

You have it exactly correct. One dedicated piccolo part, one dedicated alto flute part, and 3 flutes with the third doubling piccolo.

Comment: Thanks. I did just go through the whole score but while listening to the music.  At that speed, I could not verify my interpretation.  I need to study it in parts next.  It is nice though, it allows me to spot details that I had not without the score.